# Redirection not working when starting the app

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am trying to redirect the page if it is logged in when the app starts.

```
if (!iSLoggedIn()) {
mainView.router.loadPage({ url: 'index.html', ignoreCache: true, reload: false });}else {
$('#txtUserName').html(localStorage.getItem("fullname"));
    mainView.router.loadPage({ url: 'dashboard.html', ignoreCache: true, reload: true });}
```

The problem is when i start the app i am redirecting the page on condition but it is not behaving properly.no event or no function is firing after the redirection.but when i come back there from other page again it works. tried a lot of ways but not working.
I am using framework7.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i could find out the page code doesnt load that quick. so i used a timeout for one second. now it works fine